# R predict() returns only fitted values for nls() model

Tags: r

First of all, I would like to mention I am just a beginner in R.
I have encountered a problem when trying to predict data from a model generated by nls(). I fitted the exponential decay function into my data and everything seems to be fine, e.g. I got a decent regression line. However, when I use predict() on a new data set, it returns only fitted values.

My code is:

```
df = data.frame(Time = c(0,5,15,30), Value = c(1, 0.38484677,0.18679383, 0.06732328))

model <- nls(Value~a*exp(-b*Time), start=list(a=1, b=0.15), data = df)

plot(Value~Time, data = df)

lines(df$Time, predict(model))
```

[image: Generated plot]

```
newtime <- data.frame(Time = seq(1,20, by = 1))

pr = predict(model, newdata = newtime$Time)

pr
[1] 0.979457389 0.450112312 0.095058637 0.009225664
```

Could someone explain me please, what I am doing wrong? I know there are here some answers to that problem, but none helped me.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't think you need the `$Time` in your `newdata` argument when you call `predict.`

Comment: Solved! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newdata` parameter should be a data.frame with the same names as your input data.  When you use `newdata = newtime$Time` you are actually passing in `newtime$Time` which is not a data.frame anymore since it 'dropped' down to a vector.  You can just pass in newtime like so

```
pr = predict(model, newdata = newtime)
```